# How to change the angle of x axis ticks dynamically based on size of name?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

My charts are changing its alignments due to the size of X-axis label names. The angle of the names also change in order to make it fit in the view. I do not want any changes in the graph alignments (which I believe is due to names printed in an angle) and also want the names in X-Axis to print normally.  [Graph wrong alignment images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zepSo.png).

I have tried using the maxRotation and minRotation to 90 but here all the values are tilted to 90. I want this to be made dynamic ie. the angle must be either 0 or 90 (if the program wants to change angle).

**Chartjs code**

```
scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero : false,
                    ticks: {
                        display: false,
                        
                            },
                    grid : {
                        display : false,
                        drawTicks : false,
                        drawBorder: false
                            },
                    
                    },
                
                x: {
                    maxBarThickness: 10, 
                    ticks : {
                        color: 'black',
                        maxRotation: 90,
                        minRotation: 0,
                        autoSkip: false,
                        fontSize : 10,
                    },
                    grid : {
                        display : false,
                        drawTicks : false
                            }
                    }   
                }
```

**HTML code to hold charts**

```
<style>
    .first {
      float : left;
      width: 45%;
      margin: 10px;
    }
</style>
    <div class ="first"> <canvas id="Services"></canvas> </div>
    <div class ="first"> <canvas id="VPN"> </canvas> </div>
    <div class = "first"> <canvas id="Policy ID"></canvas> </div>
    <div class = "first"> <canvas id="Source Country"></canvas> </div>
    <div class = "first"> <canvas id="Source IP"> </canvas> </div>
    <div class = "first"> <canvas id="Destination IP"></canvas> </div>
```

How do I achieve this where I can change the tilt angle to 90 if required ?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change it in the chart config itself and then call update on the chart like so:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          minRotation: 0,
          maxRotation: 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);

document.getElementById("switch").addEventListener("click", () => {
  chart.options.scales.x.ticks.minRotation = chart.options.scales.x.ticks.minRotation === 0 ? 90 : 0;
  chart.options.scales.x.ticks.maxRotation = chart.options.scales.x.ticks.maxRotation === 0 ? 90 : 0;
  chart.update();
});
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="switch">
    Switch tick rotation
    </button>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks it looks like the solution I need but can you give me a substitute for addEventListener('click') as in my case I don't want to press a button I just want the text to automatically change its angle to 90 if an angle is required.

Comment: This is kind of hard coding right? Is there a way for me to check if an angle is required or not? if required then I will change it to 90 or else it will stay 0 degrees